# Problems trying to show the String

Tags: android, jsoup

So, I got this application that gets some text from a website using Jsoup, and then sets a `TextView` with that text.

The part where I get the text from the website seems to be fine. If I use `Log.d("", StringWithTheText);`, it will show me the text in Logcat.

The problem is that when it's going to set the `TextView`, it's just blank.

Also, if I try to put this text on a `Toast`, the `Toast` will be blank as well.

There is no exception being thrown in Logcat.

The app works fine on my phone (with Android 2.3), but that error occurs in the emulator (using Android 4.1).

Any ideas on what might be causing this issue?

Important part of the code:

```
public void novasInf() throws Exception {
    Document doc;

    doc = Jsoup.connect(StringURL).get();

    Element tituloH1 = doc.select("h1").first();
    titulo = tituloH1.text();

    Element text = doc.select("div.entry").first();
    Elements paragrafos = text.getElementsByTag("p");
    String textoFinal = "";
    for (Element x:paragrafos) {
        if (x.text().equals(".")) {
            //Fazer nada.
        }
        else {
            textoFinal += x.text()+"\n";
        }                   
    }
    texto = textoFinal;

}

private class resolveIMG extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    ProgressDialog pDialog;

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            //...
            novasInf();
            //...
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return bmp;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        try {
            pDialog.dismiss();
            ivIMG.setImageBitmap(result);
            tvTitulo.setText(titulo);
            tvTexto.setText(texto);
            primeiraVez = false;
            llP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = ProgressDialog.show(Principal.this, "", "Carregando...", true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: in your emulator, does the Log also show the correct string ? i find it impossible to be existant and be "empty" with a Toast

Comment: Please post the code to show how you're doing that.

Comment: Yes, it does. That's the odd part, the String apparently seems ok, but whenever I try to use it, it looks empty.

Comment: I posted the important part of the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probable cause is that you are using networking in the main thread. You must create another AsyncTask for the SOAP request and execute it in the main thread. Also, return the string value from that thread and then show it.

Logcat is showing the string in log because it can access it, but main thread doesn't have that string. This will also explain why the app is working on 2.3 but not on 4+.

Comment: I don't get it. I'm already using the network in the AsyncTask. Could you explain me a bit more? But I'll try returning the value, and see if it helps.

Comment: When I returned the value, I realized that I was calling the Toast at the wrong time. Just to test it, I've put it after I called the AsyncTask, not in the onPostExecute method, that's why it was empty I guess. Everything was okay, but on the wrong order. Thanks a lot!